# how to get the probability of a logistic regression result? (or any other model)

Tags: machine-learning, probability, logistic-regression

How can I tell how confidence the model is with respect to the end result? For example, say I have a logistic regression model to identify an iris (Setosa, Versicolor, Virginica).

I trained the model and at the end for a given input I get a classification of Setosa. How can I tell the probability of the model that this is a Setosa? `(example, 89% setosa, 5% Verginica and 6% versicolor)`

```
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Later I have:

```
predictions = model.predict(my_one_test)
predictions
```

but the results is the category:

```
array(['setosa'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the scikit-learn library and its LogisticRegression implementation, you can use `predict_proba(X)` to get the probability estimates ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict_proba)).

You can change your snippet to the following

```
predictions = model.predict_proba(my_one_test)
```